# installing ubuntu 13.04 divided my HDD

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I just tried installing ubuntu 13.04 and I'm sure I followed the Right steps until he loading screen after the restart required ...when it boot up it asked between win 7 disk1 or win 7 disk2. And ubuntu 13.04

Ubuntu works great but win 7 wont load and I only have one hard drive.so I think its partition.
I need win 7 for my brother but I used ubuntu for being more efficient.

What can I do to recover win 7 when the disk is divided into 2 section..why in ubuntu has a slider to choose memory but the minimum size is around 130gb for storage

Comment: please ask only one question per post. i suggest editing your question about the slider out and posting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you mount the Windows partition from Ubuntu ? Go to `Files` and under `Devices` you should see something like `100 GB Volume`. If you enter the partition and you can see that there are files from Windows then you can recover everything. Otherwise you should install an fresh copy of Windows.

Comment: No It can be found.... disk1 has win 7 but it loads the start up Icon and besides that the computer restarts automatically after 2 seconds.I manage to restore win 7 by using fatory restore program...